# How can i print the number of matches characters

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Enter first word");
     string word1 = Console.ReadLine();

   Console.WriteLine("Enter a second word");
     string word2 = Console.ReadLine();


     int count = 0;
        foreach (char obj in word1)

          if (word2.Contains(obj.ToString()))
             {
                Console.WriteLine(obj);

                  count++;
             }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

It gives me the characters that matches, but I want to print only the number of how many characters match. Can anyone help me with this, please?

e.g. If the inputs are "bla" and "bar" the output be "2", because "b" and "a" are the characters that match.

Comment: First you need to define "overlap". For "abc" and "abdc", what is the expected output? Also, is your problem really that this code prints the characters, but that you only want to print the count? Then remove the `WriteLine(obj)` and add a `WriteLine(count)`...?

Comment: Instead of `Console.Write(obj)` just `Console.Write(count)` after the loop finished.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't find overlapping characters (characters partially covering another when *printed*), it finds characters *contained* in another string. That's why the code uses `Contains`

Comment: Overlapping to me would be the first string ending in a substring the second string starts with. That is not what your code does.

Comment: Ok, I edit it, sorry for my English, I'm not an original one, so I express myself bad.

Comment: What is the expected result for `"abacus"` and `"abbreviation"`? Note that `a` and `b` appear *several* times.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you are right, I want to count which character exists in the first string and is found also in the second string.
If is found it once not to count it second time. So in the output should be only how many characters matches, not how many times.

Comment: @M16: if you want to count how many *unique* characters match (in case of `"abacus" ` and `"abbreviation"` the answer is `2` since matching characters are `a` and `b`) then `int count = word1.Intersect(word2).Count();` or `var hs = new HashSet<char>(word1); hs.IntersectWith(word2); int count = hs.Count;`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko:  And can this be solve with loops?

Answer (score 0):

having words which contain a character multible times (like word1 being car and word2 being banana) your counter would result in 3, assuming you dont want that, you can use intersect, which returns only characters that appear in both strings, and only once

```
    string word1 = "bla";
    string word2 = "bar";
    Console.WriteLine(word1.Intersect(word2).Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop solution:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter the first word");
 string word1 = Console.ReadLine();

 Console.WriteLine("Enter the second word");
 string word2 = Console.ReadLine();

 HashSet<char> processed = new HashSet<char>();

 int count = 0;

 foreach (char c in word1) 
   if (processed.Add(c))        // If c a new character  
     if (word2.IndexOf(c) >= 0) // and it's found within word2 
       count += 1;

 Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Here we count *unique* characters only, i.e. we want to get `2` for `"abacus"` and `"abbreviations"` (`'a'` and `'b'` chars)